# Solve cubic equation $x^3-9 x^2-15x-6 =0$ without going Cardano

Tags: algebra-precalculus, cubics

> Solve the cubic equation for $x\in\mathbb{R}$ $$x^3-9 x^2-15x-6 =0$$

Note that the only real solution is $x=3+2\sqrt[3]{7}+\sqrt[3]{7^2}$. Given the *regularity* of this solution, can we solve for it constructively, without going full [Cardano?](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cubic_function#Cardano.27s_method).

Also, can we prove that there is only one real solution without using the discriminant?

Comment: At least checking that there is only one solution is easy. Just differentiate and check the local extrema.

Comment: Well, the solution itself suggests a substitution $y=x-3$ might be helpful.

Comment: @DavidH Yup, that would give us the depressed cubic $y^3=42y+105$. But I don't see an obvious way to suppose that $y=\sqrt[3]{a}+\sqrt[3]{b}$.

Comment: What does it mean for the solution $3 + 2\sqrt[3]{7} + \sqrt[3]{7^2}$ to be *regular*?

Comment: Could it mean $3 + 2\sqrt[3]{7} + \sqrt[3]{7^2}$ is of multiplicity one?

Comment: $x=(1/(2/7^{1/3} - 1) - 1)/2$

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the Cardano’s method, substituting $x=3+2\sqrt{14}\cosh t$ into $x^3-9 x^2-15x-6=0$ to get
$$4\cosh^3t-3\cosh t = \cosh 3t = \frac{15}{4\sqrt{14}}$$
which leads to $t=\frac13\cosh^{-1}\frac{15}{4\sqrt{14}}$ and, then, the solution
$$x=3+2\sqrt{14}\cosh\left(\frac13\cosh^{-1}\frac{15}{4\sqrt{14}}\right)$$
which is numerically equal to $3+2\sqrt[3]{7}+\sqrt[3]{49}$.

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $x=\frac1{t-1}$ to translate $x^3-9 x^2-15x-6 =0$ into
$$6t^3-3t^2-3t-1=0$$
and then rewrite it as $7t^3=(t+1)^3$,
which yields $t=\frac1{\sqrt[3]7-1}$ and in turn the solution
$$x= \frac1{t-1} =\frac{\sqrt[3]7-1}{2-\sqrt[3]7}=\sqrt[3]{49}+\sqrt[3]7+3
$$

Answer (score 0):

If $y=x-3$ and $y^3-42y=105$, then take $y=t+r\implies t^3+r^3+(3tr-42)y=105$, then: 
$$3tr-42=0$$$$t^3+r^3=105$$

$$3tr-42=0\implies tr=14\implies t^3r^3=2744$$
Then $t^3$, and $r^3$ are roots of:
$$Z^2-105Z+2744=0$$
Then $Z_1=49$ and $Z_2=56$, $\implies t^3=49$ and $r^3=56$, $\implies t=\sqrt[3]{7^2}$ and $r=2\sqrt[3]{7}$

Comment: This looks pretty similar to good ol', bad ol' ***full Cardano*** to me!

Answer (score 0):

When you say "full Cardano" are you referring to using a formula? Because there is a *process* for solving a cubic that is constructive. But maybe you do not want this because it is essentially how to construct Cardano's formula.

Substituting $x=y+3$ leads to:

$$\begin{align}
x^3-9x^2-15x-6&=0\\
(y+3)^3-9(y+3)^2-15(y+3)-6&=0\\
y^3-42y-105&=0
\end{align}$$

Now introduce parameters $u$ and $v$ such that their sum is a solution $y$:
$$\begin{align}
(u+v)^3-42(u+v)-105&=0\\
u^3+v^3+(3uv-42)(u+v)-105&=0
\end{align}$$
We have freedom to choose $u$ such that $3uv-42=0$. That implies $v=\frac{14}{u}$ and simplifies the equation above:
$$\begin{align}
u^3+\left(\frac{14}{u}\right)^3-105&=0\\
u^6-105u^3+14^3&=0
\end{align}$$
This is quadratic in $u^3$:
$$\begin{align}
u^3&=\frac{105\pm\sqrt{105^2-4\cdot14^3}}{2}\\
u^3&=\frac{105\pm7}{2}\\
\end{align}$$
You may assume the "$+$" for $u^3$, since the "$-$" would give the symmetric $v^3$.
$$\begin{align}
u^3&=\frac{105+7}{2}=56\\
u&=2\sqrt[3]{7}
\end{align}$$
From which $v=\frac{14}{2\sqrt[3]{7}}=\frac{7}{\sqrt[3]{7}}=\sqrt[3]{7^2}$.

And now $x=y+3=u+v+3=2\sqrt[3]{7}+\sqrt[3]{7^2}+3$.

Answer (score 0):

Let cubic equation $f=ax+bx^2+cx^3$, then for equation $x^3 - 9 x^2 - 15 x - 6 = 0$ we have $a=-15,b=-9,c=1,f=6$.

Non-Cardano cubic formula:

$X=\dfrac{-(a b+9 c f)+\sqrt{(a b+9 c f)^2-4 (b^2-3 a c) (a^2+3 b f)}}{2 (b^2-3 a c)}=-1/2$

$A=a+2 b X+3 c X^2=-21/4$

$F=a X+b X^2+c X^3-f=-7/8$

$G=A^3-27 c F^2=-1323/8$

$Q=\Big\{G^{1/3},-(-1)^{1/3} G^{1/3},(-1)^{2/3} G^{1/3}\Big\}=\Big\{(3/2) (-1)^{1/3} 7^{2/3}, -(3/2) (-7)^{2/3}, -(3/2) 7^{2/3}\Big\}$

$x=X+\dfrac{3 F}{Q-A}=\Big\{-(1/2)\Big(1+\dfrac{7}{7 + 2 (-1)^{1/3} 7^{2/3}}\Big), \dfrac{7 - (-7)^{2/3}}{-7 + 2 (-7)^{2/3}},\dfrac{7 - 7^{2/3}}{-7 + 2\cdot 7^{2/3}}\Big\}=\\
\Big\{3 - 7^{1/3} - 7^{2/3}/2 - i \sqrt{3} (-7^{1/3} + 7^{2/3}/2), 3 - 2 (-7)^{1/3} + (-7)^{2/3}, 3 + 2\cdot 7^{1/3} + 7^{2/3}\Big\}=\\
\Big\{-0.742584 + 0.144242\cdot i, -0.742584 - 0.144242\cdot i, 10.4852\Big\}$

And note: $z^3=w \implies z=\Big\{w^{1/3},-(-1)^{1/3}w^{1/3},(-1)^{2/3}w^{1/3}\Big\}$,

where $\Big\{-(-1)^{1/3},(-1)^{2/3}\Big\}=\Big\{e^{-2\pi\cdot i/3},e^{2\pi\cdot i/3}\Big\}=\Big\{-0.5 - 0.866025\cdot i, -0.5 + 0.866025\cdot i\Big\}$